# Domain Name without "www" does not work for CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-cloudfront

I have

1. An AWS S3 bucket as a static site
2. A CloudFront distribution with ACM SSL certs
3. A Name.com domain name
4. A Heroku web app

I successfully have `www.domain.com` pointing to my `abc123.cloudfront.net` website. I also have `api.domain.com` successfully pointing towards my `heroku` app. I used ACM to generate a certificate for `www.domain.com` and Heroku handles its own SSL stuff as well.

That's pretty good, but just to be anal, I want `domain.com` to also point to my CF address. However it does not. This is how I set up my CF and DNS and wonder if anyone has any ideas. I've gone through about 20 SO questions and articles with no luck. Also `Name.com` URL forward does not seem to work.

**DNS Settings**
[image: DNS]

---

**CloudFront Settings**
[image: CF Settings]

Comment: You need to explicitly add record pointing `domain.com` to CF. Also your certificate must cover `domain.com`, not only `*.domain.com`.

Comment: A DNS record, or a CNAME to CF? Is the DNS otherwise fine?

Comment: I'm not sure what ANAME is in `Name.com`.  Your CNAME in CF also should include `domain.com`. Please note that `*.domain.com` does not cover `domain.com`. So you have to explicitly use both if you want `domain.com`. This means in your DNS records, CNAMES in CF, SSL certificates, etc.

Comment: An ANAME record is a Name.com-specific feature that automatically finds and updates A and AAAA records from the target. Unlike CNAME records, ANAMEs can be placed next to other records (one per hostname). ANAME records are commonly known as ALIAS records or CNAME flattening.

Comment: I was able to use an `@` and now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you don't mind I will provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

Currently, only `www.domain.com` record is used to direct connections to CloudFront (CF) distro. To direct `domain.com`, a **new record** should be created which also points to the CF distro in `Name.com` DNS.

In addition to these, **CNAME** in CF as well as **SSL** certificate should also include `domain.com`.

Comment: I've followed everything mentioned above. My Domain is in Google Domains and has a CNAME for www pointing to CF. CF has both www.domain.com and domain.com record. SSL certificate is for both too. I yet cannot get https colon slash slash domain.com to work. Please help.