# S3 static hosted website not working without www. (Namecheap DNS, Cloudfront Distro, ACM SSL Cert)

Tags: amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, aws-acm-certificate

I can't seem to resolve this one issue. Without www it doesn't work. For background it was originally pointing to a www. bucket but I've since made a new one and it's pointing to that one. I have a namecheap CNAME records pointing to cloudfront (added the * host CNAME today):
[image]

Cloudfront:

[image]

[image]

S3:

[image]

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @jellycsc "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND camelsoftware.io"

Comment: your wildcard CNAME entry does not include your root/apex domain `camelsoftware.io`, it only includes `*.camelsoftware.io`

Comment: @DusanBajic the CNAME requires a host, how can I make it include the root/apex domain?

Comment: I was able to do it with an @ in the host portion of the CNAME, thanks for pointing it out, this helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073615/domain-name-without-www-does-not-work-for-cloudfront

Answer (score 0):

For the CNAME record portion of the set up I just added a @ as the host, [this link helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66073615/domain-name-without-www-does-not-work-for-cloudfront)